# What is ":" in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax

What does the symbol `:` mean in PHP?

Comment: Could you please post the code that it appears in? It could have different meanings, depending on the context.

Comment: When asking a questions please `be specific`. Oftentimes, this means giving a code example.

Comment: Scope Resolution Operator(:)    http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Answer (score 35, accepted):

PHP offers an alternative syntax for some of its control structures; namely, if, while, for, foreach, and switch. In each case, the basic form of the alternate syntax is to change the opening brace to a colon (:) and the closing brace to endif;, endwhile;, endfor;, endforeach;, or endswitch;, respectively.

Answer (score 21):

You also encounter `:` if you use the [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php):

```
<?php
if ($a == 5):
    echo "a equals 5";
    echo "...";
elseif ($a == 6):
    echo "a equals 6";
    echo "!!!";
else:
    echo "a is neither 5 nor 6";
endif;
?>
```

Or as already mentioned the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
$action = (empty($_POST['action'])) ? 'default' : $_POST['action'];
```

*(Examples taken from the documentation)*

---

**Edit:** Somehow I didn't see that the alternative syntax was already mentioned, must be too tired ;) Anyway, I will leave it as it is, as I think an actual example and a link to the documentation is more helpful than just plain text.

Comment: Third place would be the `foreach ( $entry : $list)` thing wouldnt it?

Comment: Could you please help me.I'm doubtful about the use of  '  :  ' in the following context ( Laravel ).    ['email' => 'required|email|unique:email,users']

Comment: @Michel: I don’t know about Laravel, sorry. From PHP‘s perspective, `:` is part of a string so it has no special meaning.

Answer (score 9):

I'm guessing you're seeing this syntax:

```
print ($item ? $item : '');
```

This is a short form of if/else. The ? is the if, and the : is the else.

Answer (score 3):

Shorter if statement:

```
$val = (condition) ? "condition is true" : "condition is false";
```

Answer (score 1):

It can mean a number of things. You may mean the [ternary operator](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/3/12/4), `?:`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have posted, you probably are looking at ternary logic.

However, if two of them are together, then it is the [scope resolution operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php), used for referencing status methods/properties and constants.