# What does ":" mean in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is “:” in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908095)

What does the `:` mean in the following PHP code?

```
<?php
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
```

Comment: this is the alternate syntax of some language construct like if while foreach

Comment: Hard to find, but some explanations here: [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's called an [Alternative Syntax For Control Structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).  You should have an `endwhile;` somewhere after that.  Basically, it allows you to omit braces `{}` from a while to make it look "prettier"...

As far as your edit, it's called the [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (it's the third section).  Basically it's an assignment shorthand.

```
$foo = $first ? $second : $third;
```

is the same as saying (Just shorter):

```
if ($first) {
    $foo = $second;
} else {
    $foo = $third;
}
```

Comment: @Shikiryu: I agree completely.  I personally don't care for it (I'd rather have the braces), but it's perfectly valid and acceptable to use (and lots of people prefer it).

Comment: I removed the Ternary Operator part, because it's not this case, but your answer is excellent and helped me understand better.

Answer (score 14):

There is an example listed in the [documentation for `while`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) that explains the syntax:

> Like with the if statement, you can group multiple statements within the same while loop by surrounding a group of statements with curly braces, or by using the alternate syntax:
>
> ```
> while (expr):
>     statement
>     ...
> endwhile;
> ```

---

An answer [over here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080202121355AAAMSl9) explains it like this:

> This (:) operator mostly used in embedded coding of php and html.
>
> Using this operator you can avoid use of curly brace. This operator reduce complexity in embedded coding. You can use this(:) operator with if, while, for, foreach and more...
>
> Without (:) operator
>
> ```
> <body>
> <?php if(true){ ?>
> <span>This is just test</span>
> <?php } ?>
> </body>
> ```
>
> With (:) operator
>
> ```
> <body>
> <?php if(true): ?>
> <span>This is just test</span>
> <?php endif; ?>
> </body>
> ```

Answer (score 8):

it's like:

```
<?php
while(have_posts()) {
    the_post();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

This notation is to avoid the use of curly braces - generally when embedding PHP within HTML -  and is equivalent to:

```
while (have_posts())
{
    the_post();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's saying while `have_posts()` is `true` run `the_post()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (expression is true : code is executed if expression is true)
```

Comment: Isn't "sentence is true" the condition?

Comment: Yes, I noticed my flaw, sorry ;o)

Answer (score -2):

```
while(expression = true) : run some code ;
```

Comment: Huh?  State the obvious much?

Comment: obvious questions = obvious answers?

Comment: But your code is wrong, since the colon does not indicate the start of a single line loop, it's the start of alternate syntax, so you'd need a `endwhile;` somewhere to terminate the loop.  So you just restated the exact code the OP posted with different names, and expect that to be an explanation of what's going on?

Comment: it makes sense to me :) Well that's not saying much... :/