# php `:` symbol usage

Tags: php

I'm wondering, what are the cases for `:` use?

I know only of:

```
if(expression):
    // do Something
endif;

while(expression):
    // and others: `for` `foreach` etc.
endwhile;
```

Are there any other uses?

Comment: I'm not a fan of this syntax and haven't seen it in any other places than i view "templates"

Comment: all control structures may use this alternative syntax. it is widely used when PHP is embedded within HTML views. typically I have seen people use normal syntax in their business logic (controllers and models), and alternative syntax within views. I believe it helps see the ends of control structures better when intermixed into HTML, therefore making it easier to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> PHP offers an alternative syntax for some of its control structures; namely, `if`, `while`, `for`, `foreach`, and `switch`. In each case, the basic form of the alternate syntax is to change the opening brace to a colon (`:`) and the closing brace to `endif;`, `endwhile;`, `endfor;`, `endforeach;`, or `endswitch;`, respectively.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: -1'd because the answer originally was *just* a link and I'm in a bad mood and hate FGITW, will rescind although the answer is still far from complete. @dqhendricks

Comment: on this day in history: i learned what 'FGITW' is.

Comment: @WesleyMurch For the record, I don't try to FGITW; I just happen to occasionally ask people to RTFM when there's a manual page specifically devoted to the concept.

Comment: Well you can cast a vote to close as dupes of these ones if you're on the RTFM tip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908095/what-is-this-in-php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747761/what-does-this-mean-in-php Found by Googling "`php : symbol`" (once again, I'm a little pissy today, sry)

Answer (score 4):

Ternary conditions: `($a == $b) ? true : false`.
Static calls inside a class: `self::$a`.
Static methods calls: `MyClass::MyMethod()`,
Static variables inside a class: `MyClass::MyVariable`
Parent methods calls: `parent::hello()`

Answer (score 3):

`switch` uses it for `case 123:` and `default:`.

`::` is used to access static class members.

Answer (score 2):

It is also used as part of the ternary operator "?:".

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php