# what does the symbol : mean in php?

Tags: php

I used `print_r` on some variables of a framework to figure out their contents and what i saw was like this

```
Array (
   [pages:navigation] => Navigation
   [pages:via] => via pages
   [item:object:page_top] => Top-level pages
)
```

I thought this was ok because i can create arrays like

```
$ar=array('pages:navigation' => 'Navigation',
           'pages:via' => 'via pages');
```

and it would be no problem but when i create this

```
class student {
   public $name;
   public function get_name()  {
      return $name;
   }
   private $id;
   public function get_id() {
      return $id;
   }
   protected $email;
}

$s = new student();
$s->name="hi";
print_r($s);
```

I get this:

```
student Object ( [name] => hi [id:student:private] => [email:protected] => )
```

here the symbol `:` is automatically inserted for `id` indicating that it is a member of `student` and is `private` but it is not inserted for `public` member `name`

I cant figure out what does the symbol `:` actually mean? Is it some kind of namespacing?

Comment: P.Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908095/what-is-this-in-php

Comment: @Mobinga: no its not.in that ques its not clear wat the OP is asking for. may be he is looking for ternary operator or something. just the title is same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the array, it has no special meaning. It's just part of the string key; an array key can be any string or integer.

In the object, it's just how `print_r` displays property names for private properties.

In `id:student:private`, `id` is the property name, `student` the class in which the property is declared, and `private` is the visibility of the property.

Comment: any reason that this symbol `:` is used only for private and potected members? does this symbol mean anything more than a separator?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are it's what the script/page is using to separate values in the `key` of the array. They may use spaces in key names so using a space wasn't acceptable and needed a character that wouldn't normally be found in the value itself.

Much like namespaces in many other languages use the `.` as a delimiter, that script decided to use `:` (which is then parsed at a later date most likely and used as its originally intended).

Without seeing the script in it's entirety, this would only be a guess as to implementation.