# what is the use of colon in php? why is colon ":" used in conditional operators and what do they stand for?

Tags: php

I searched alot on the internet but couldnt find the use of : in php. 
Someone please explain this to me. Thanks

I have a statement like this

```
   $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

and i want to understand what : is used for here.

Comment: It's the alternative syntax, [see](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php)

Comment: @hanky-panky A better duplicate for this question might be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908095/what-is-in-php/2908114#2908114

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, didn't see that one before

Comment: alternative for what? could you please explain?

Comment: Alternative syntax to curly braces `while($loop->have_posts()) { $loop->the_post(); }`