# I need explanation for what does this expression mean

Tags: php

I'm only a beginner in PHP, but I see many times in PHP code something like this:

```
<?php if(!empty($field)) : ?>
// HTML code
<?php endif; ?>
```

What there's a need to use `:` here, after the expression? If it's a shorthand, then why there's no `?` immediately after the expression? And how this(the above code) should be read(in words, please)?

Thank you

Comment: [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: It's a quite common way to write it in templates (views) for it to be clearer than a bunch of nested `{` and `}` mixed with HTML. You can read more about it in the link that @Ivar posted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is ":" in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908095/what-is-in-php)

Comment: Thank you! Thank you a lot guys!